# Bash test effective (paginated) lines of file before displaying

Tags: bash, less-unix

I just created a script to display the contents of a file, either with `cat` or with `less` based on the number of effective (post-line-wrap) number of lines in the file. To be clear, what I have works well, I'm just curious if anyone has something better handy.

```sh
if [ $(stat -c '%s' "${ERRLOG}") -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "${ERRLOG}"
    if [ -n "${COLUMNS}" -a "$(grep -o ".{0, ${COLUMNS}}" "${ERRLOG}" | wc -l)" -gt "${ROWS}" ]; then
        less "${ERRLOG}"
    else
        cat "${ERRLOG}"
    fi
fi
```

While I'm rather proud of using `grep -o`, which splits multiple pattern matches within the same source line into multiple lines, I suspect there's a better way to do this, preferably one that does not parse through the contents of the file twice. Maybe something with awk?

Credit to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184009/how-do-i-find-number-of-vertical-lines-available-in-the-terminal) for the use of `$ROWS` and `$COLUMNS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`less` has that functionality built-in:

> `-F` or `--quit-if-one-screen`
>   Causes `less` to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

Options you always want to use can be set in the `$LESS` environment variable.

For `less` versions older than 530, the `-X`/`--no-init` option has to be used additionally; see the [release notes for `less` 530](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.530.html):

> Don't output terminal init sequence if using `-F` and file fits on one screen.

Comment: That's not working for me. It quits without printing anything. Upvoted anyway because it's probably the right answer for most people.

Comment: @memtha What version of `less` do you have? Older version might require also setting `-X`/`--no-init`.

Comment: less 436 (c)1984-2009 Mark Nudelman ... greenwoodsoftware.com/less.  The one that comes in mingw msys. Works with `-X`. Thx. Is `-X` portable or must I test less version?

Comment: @memtha It was fixed in less 530; I think always using `-X` doesn't break things.